# How to position form Dialog in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created a simple form with https://material-ui.com/

Mt form has two fields:

[image]

I have implemented a form Dialog popup when user clicks in the "Booking name" field.

The problem is that my Dialog is partly covered by a keyboard. I want Dialog move up when keyboard is shown.

Any ideas how to fix it:

[image]

Here is my Dialoge code:

```
<Dialog open={this.state.booking_name_dialog_open} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title" maxWidth={"lg"} fullWidth={true}>
    <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Booking name:</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
        <TextField autoFocus margin="dense" id="name" label="Booking name" type="text" fullWidth/>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <Button color="primary">Cancel</Button>
        <Button color="primary">Submit</Button>
    </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was because of StatusBar plugin. Just don't use it and you won't have such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your form inside  core component from react-native

import {keyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
<form>
</form>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 'cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard' plugin https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard and check whether it solves.